# Matching User 's Input With Nested Dictionary in Python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.7

I cannot seem to match the user `input(num)` to `id_num` to print out the individual license info. I want that when the user is prompted to enter the license number, the code should loop through the dictionary and find its match and print the info that matches the input.

I tried:

1. if num in driver_license[id_num]:
2. if num==id_num:
3. if num==int(id_num):

```py
42456 :{'name': 'jill', 'ethnicity': 'hispanic','eye': 'yellow' ,'height': '6.1'},

44768 :{'name': 'cheroky', 'ethnicity': 'native','eye': 'green' ,'height': '6.7'},

32565 :{'name': 'valentina', 'ethnicity': 'european','eye': 'fair','height': '4.9'}}


print('\n')
print('- ' *45)


for id_num, id_info in driver_license.items():
    num = int(input('Enter your driving license number: '))

    print(f"Id number: {id_num}")
    name=f"{id_info['name']}"
    origin= f"{id_info ['ethnicity']}"
    eye= f"{id_info['eye']}"
    height=f"{id_info['height']}"

    if num in driver_license[id_num]:
        print(f'\nId number is:{num}')
        print(f'Name: {name}')
        print(f'Ethnicity: {origin}')
        print(f'Eyes color: {eye}')
        print(f'Height: {height}\n')
    else:
        print('Invalid ID')
```

There is no error but a mismatch of output than expected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through the dictionary.

You can instead use [get(key, default)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to get the entry from the `driver_license` dictionary using the input license number as the key.  You can then set `default` to some value to handle the case where the key is not in the `dict` (here I used `None`).

```py
driver_license = {
    "42456" : {'name': 'jill', 'ethnicity': 'hispanic','eye': 'yellow' ,'height': '6.1'},
    "44768" : {'name': 'cheroky', 'ethnicity': 'native','eye': 'green' ,'height': '6.7'},
    "32565" : {'name': 'valentina', 'ethnicity': 'european','eye': 'fair','height': '4.9'}
}

id_num = input('Enter your driving license number: ')
# if user enters "32565"

id_info = driver_license.get(id_num, None)  
# id_info would be:
#    {'name': 'valentina', 'ethnicity': 'european','eye': 'fair','height': '4.9'}

if id_info:
    print(f'\nId number is:{id_num }')
    print(f'Name: {id_info["name"]}')
    print(f'Ethnicity: {id_info["ethnicity"]}')
    print(f'Eyes color: {id_info["eye"]}')
    print(f'Height: {id_info["height"]}\n')
else:
    print('Invalid ID')
```